# Connect Heroku Postgres DB to Kettle

Tags: postgresql, heroku, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I want to connect kettle to postgres db on heroku for doing an upload of some data.
From Kettle I make a new DB connection, in connection type I choose PostgreSQL and I put all the settings that I found on heroku, but the test connection to DB fail. This is the log that I receive

```
Errore di connessione al database [DB_CONNECTION_HEROKU] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "xxxxx", database "xxxxx", SSL off


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "xxxx", database "xxxxx", SSL off


    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:472)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2795)
    at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:598)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:43)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:80)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:47)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:116)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:60)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.step.BaseStepDialog.showDbDialogUnlessCancelledOrValid(BaseStepDialog.java:779)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.step.BaseStepDialog$AddConnectionListener.widgetSelected(BaseStepDialog.java:1374)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.sql.ExecSQLDialog.open(ExecSQLDialog.java:599)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:127)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:8789)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:3179)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.mouseDoubleClick(TransGraph.java:775)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1359)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7990)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9290)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:685)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "xxxxxxxx", database "xxxxxxxxx", SSL off

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:585)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "xxxxx", database "xxxxx", SSL off
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:408)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:181)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:144)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:567)
    ... 53 more

Nome dell'host: xxxxxx
Porta:5432
Nome database: xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku prides itself to enforce secure connections to your database, so you should add parameter ssl=true to your connection. Also, you may want to edit your post to remove remaining privacy issues.

Edit1: To use driver parameters not part of the connection URL, open the database connection object and add parameters on page "Options".

Edit2: Make sure you have prepared your Java VM to accept the Heroku server certificate by [adding it to your truststore](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/ssl-client.html).

Comment: How I can add ssl=true? Where?

Comment: Your database connection object has a page named "Options" where you can enter parameters you otherwise would add to the driver URL.

Comment: When I add the options ssl=true to db connection I receive this error [log](http://pastebin.com/QRFY0gF7)

Comment: Now work, I add this options sslfactory = org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory